# SQL Server : Row Number without ordering

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a `Select` statement that ranks the column as is without ordering.

Currently, the table is in the following order:

```
ITEM_Description1
ITEM_Description2
ITEM_StockingType
ITEM_RevisionNumber
```

I do not want the results to be numerical in any way, nor depend on the `VariableID` numbers, but with `ROW_Number()`, I have to choose something. Does anyone know how I can have the results look like this?

```
Row| VariableName
---------------------
 1 | ITEM_Description1
 2 | ITEM_Description2
 3 | ITEM_StockingType
 4 | ITEM_RevisionNumber
```

My code for an example is shown below.

```
SELECT  
    VariableName, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY VariableID) AS RowNumber
FROM    
    SeanVault.dbo.TempVarIDs
```

Comment: If you do this, your results will be nondeterministic - there's no guarantee that your records will be returned in the same order each time. Is that really what you want? Just because you're seeing this ordering right now doesn't mean that you'll *always* see this ordering.

Comment: @SeanDon: What you're attempting to do doesn't appear to make much sense. Even if you find a way to do this, the row numbers will be little better than random numbers. What problem are you trying to solve with them?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do... In your case Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY NULL) as RowN will help

Comment: `Row_Number() over ( order by NULL )` will give you numbers (subject to alroc's comment).

Comment: I apologize I forgot to come back to this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) will give you the results your looking for.

SELECT
    VariableName, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum
FROM
    SeanVault.dbo.TempVarIDs

Comment: To clarify, SELECT NULL will give you the results that you are looking for based on my understanding of your question. You stated that you want the records ranked without ordering, ranked by what?

Comment: I basically just want to number the list. the first resulting row to say 1, the second 2, and so on. I want to then use those numbers elsewhere. At that specific moment, I have rowIDs. At this time, since its been a month, I do not recall the exact issue and will need to dig into it again for a better way to answer your question. I apologize for not having all the info to respond, but I made a workaround last month to keep moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be with this sentence:

> Currently, the table is in the following order:

**No, your table is NOT implicitly ordered!!**

Although it might look like this...

The only way to enforce the resultset's sort order is an `ORDER BY`-clause at the outer most `SELECT`.

If you want to maintain the sort order of your inserts you can use

- a column like `ID INT IDENTITY` (which will automatically increase a sequence counter)

Using `GETDATE()` on insert will not solve this, as multiple row inserts might get the same DateTime value.

You do not have to show this in your output of course...

Answer (score 0):

Your table has no inherent order.  Even if you get that order a 100 times in a row is no guarantee it will be that order on the 101 time.

You can add an identity column to the table.